# XCTest : How to hit a button from an array

Tags: xctest, xctestcase

I have a view and five buttons in an array on a uistackview drawn on a storey board:
However, when I record, it always hit the third button and I cannot randomise which button to hit
Code is:

```
 let app = XCUIApplication()
        let oneElement = app.otherElements["First"]
        let twoElement = app.otherElements["Two"]

 if oneElement.exists
            {
                oneElement.tap()
            }

            if twoElement.exists
            {
            twoElement.tap()

            }
```

TwoElement is the one that taps the button
How can I direct the tap to button 1 or 0?

Comment: Please post the output of `app.buttons.debugDescription`.

Comment: Also, why are you using `otherElements` if you are looking for buttons?

Answer (score 0):

otherelements is what was provided by the recording.  I will sned the debug description in a few hours

Comment: output of app.debugdescription:

Answer (score 0):

```
otherElements
```

is what was provided by the recording.  I will send the debug description in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

this is what was provided by the recording.  I will send the debug description in a few hours